# Facing error while transforming xml to xsd file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I tried to transform **XML to XSD**, the DSD result was saved on `XmlSchemaSet`.

I tried the folowing code:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(input);
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
XmlSchemaInference schema = new XmlSchemaInference();
schemaSet = schema.InferSchema(reader);
schemaSet.Add(null, "result.xsd");
```

But I have the following problem:

`missing root node`

Comment: it would help to see the xml

Comment: Is the root node missing?

Comment: What does your `input` hold?

Comment: On which line you are getting error.

Comment: the xml is the following:<root xmlns="..."><messges><phoneNumber></phoneNumber><message><message></messages></root>

Comment: *there are the xml: – user2541552 22 secs ago* Yeah you're going to need some XML to transform...

Comment: i get the error on the last line